# Paypal pass-through variable?

Tags: paypal, joomla, paypal-sandbox

I have looked at the [paypal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091627/how-do-i-pass-session-variables-to-paypal-with-buy-now-button).

It seems pass-through variables only have 3:

- custom
- item_number or item_number_x
- invoice

I want to use custom, but it is already used by one of the plugin. (I am using joomla)

Is there any variable that I can use as pass-through variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend saving any data you need to the order (I'm assuming you're using VirtueMart on Joomla..??)

Then you can pass that order ID into the invoice parameter, and then pull data back out of the order that you need based on that order ID.

If you're using VirtueMart it would be the same flow.  Just save all the data you need to your order/invoice record, then pull it back out when you need it based on the invoice value PayPal has.